# Showing the GMT time with momentjs

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I started using `momentjs` a while ago. I was using before `Date` in order to covert `epochtime` to a nice format. Example:

```
return new Date(1000 * parseInt(timestamp));
```

Output:

```
Sun Apr 14 2019 21:23:38 GMT+0300 (Sarajevo Daylight Time)
```

I would like to get the following format:

```
Apr 14 2019 21:23:38 GMT+0300
```

So I tried to use `momentjs`. The format I used is: `"MMM DD, YYYY HH:mm:ss"` but it returns without `GMT+0300`. What format should I add?
For now what I did is:

```
 moment.unix(timestamp).format("MMM DD, YYYY HH:mm:ss")
```

Output: `Apr 14 2019 21:23:38`. 
Tried to read the docs but I could not find information about it.

Comment: Does it have to be GMT and not UTC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ZZ` to get offset and use `"MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss [GMT]ZZ"` to get the desired format.

```js
console.log(moment.unix(1555424726).format("MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss [GMT]ZZ"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.js"></script>
```